# Pyspark - Issue creating a dataframe from RDD using a defined schema

Tags: json, pyspark, schema, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to convert a RDD to a dataframe using the `createDataFrame` function and a defined `schema` and store the resultant dataframe as json:

```
df_final = sqlContext.createDataFrame(my_rdd, schema)
df_final.write.json('/tmp/data')
```

The RDD contains the following Rows:

```
{"obj1": {"name": "ABC", "dateCreatedUtc": "2017-06-23 00:00:00", "pair1": {"lat": 60.82349395751953, "lon": -8.173828125}, "pair2": {"lat": 49.16015625, "lon": 1.867676019668579}}, "obj2": {"name": "DEF", "pair1": {"lat": "0.00", "lon": "0.00"},  "pair2": {"lat": "0.00", "lon": "0.00"}}}
{"obj1": {"name": "GHI", "dateCreatedUtc": "2017-06-23 00:00:00", "pair1": {"lat": 10.43567890021344, "lon": -17.34675465}, "pair2": {"lat": 80.36473824, "lon": 4.557957859758945}}, "obj2": {"name": "JKL", "pair1": {"lat": "0.00", "lon": "0.00"},  "pair2": {"lat": "0.00", "lon": "0.00"}}}
...
...
...
```

I tried defining the `schema` as follows:

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField('obj1', MapType(StringType(), MapType(StringType(), StringType(), True), True), True),
    StructField('obj2', MapType(StringType(), MapType(StringType(), StringType(), True), True), True)
])
```

The code runs fine but when I check my output json file, the rows look like as follows:

```
{"obj1": {"name": null, "dateCreatedUtc": null, "pair1": {"lat": 60.82349395751953, "lon": -8.173828125}, "pair2": {"lat": 49.16015625, "lon": 1.867676019668579}}, "obj2": {"name": null, "pair1": {"lat": "0.00", "lon": "0.00"},  "pair2": {"lat": "0.00", "lon": "0.00"}}}
{"obj1": {"name": null, "dateCreatedUtc": null, "pair1": {"lat": 10.43567890021344, "lon": -17.34675465}, "pair2": {"lat": 80.36473824, "lon": 4.557957859758945}}, "obj2": {"name": null, "pair1": {"lat": "0.00", "lon": "0.00"},  "pair2": {"lat": "0.00", "lon": "0.00"}}}
```

TL;DR - All the fields except the lat and lons have been populated with null values.

I can see that this implies a schema mismatch between the RDD Rows and the schema that I defined. However, I am not able to figure out the problem with the schema since I have catered/think that I have catered for the nested json structure.

Would appreciate any help/pointers in regard to this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MapType` is not the way to go to represent data with mixed types. Correct schema for example records (I assume these are Python `dicts`) would be:

```
StructType([
    StructField("obj1", StructType([
        StructField("dateCreatedUtc", StringType(), True), 
        StructField("name", StringType(), True), 
        StructField("pair1", StructType([
            StructField("lat", DoubleType(), True), 
            StructField("lon", DoubleType(), True)
        ]), True), 
        StructField("pair2", StructType([
            StructField("lat", DoubleType(), True), 
            StructField("lon", DoubleType(), True)
        ]),  True)
    ]), True), 
    StructField("obj2", StructType([
        StructField("name", StringType(), True), 
        StructField("pair1", StructType([
            StructField("lat", StringType(), True), 
            StructField("lon", StringType(), True)
        ]), True), 
        StructField("pair2", StructType([
            StructField("lat", StringType(), True), 
            StructField("lon", StringType(), True)
        ]), True)
    ]), True)
])
```